# After install 'ng2-cookies why cookie.SetCooki not showing

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-cookie

I am using `ng2-cookies`, but when I try to use `setCookie`, it's not showing intelligence.

I get the error here:

```
 Cookie.setCookie('')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.as the doc say `https://github.com/BCJTI/ng2-cookies/wiki/Static-Class-%7C-Minimum-Example`
 .. you need to `IMPORt it`

```
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies';
```

Comment: could u plz Help Me why im getting Error as   XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5179/node_modules/ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies.js/ng2-cookies.js

Comment: post your code ..  have  you instealled it with npm?

Comment: yes i install From npm  These r my Previous  urls in System.config.js            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

Comment: Now i added as              'ng2-cookies': 'npm:ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies.js',

Comment: any idea @federico

Comment: i use angular-cli